UT8805E Pyvisa E0FError
I am trying to communicate with a Uni-Trend UT8805E digital multimeter using Python and pyvisa.  I am able to open a connection, an write a command to the device, but when I try to read, I get an EOFError.
I want to be able to send commands and read outputs from the multimeter.  I suspect I am not properly loading the results into the output buffer, but I've tried everything I can find in the programming manual to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
